# AudioInputStream to an array

Tags: java, javasound

I need to get the values from the AudioInputStream and store it in a byte[]. Calling a read(byte[]) returns -1. If I'm able to read the values as integers, I can convert it to byte[]. How do I get around either of the problems ?

Comment: If read(byte[]) returns -1, it means that there's nothing more to read. Show the code you're using, you're probably constructing the inputsream wrong.

Comment: Can you tell us the format of the audio file? Maybe it is not be an accepted format (e.g., instead of 16-bit, it might be 24- or 32-bit encoding). The best example code for reading a file in the Java Tutorials is in the following section. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html in the section "reading sound files"

Comment: AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(44100, 16,1,true,false); I capture the audio using mic and want to read the values into a byte[]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java How to store the audio data in a byte array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169044/java-how-to-store-the-audio-data-in-a-byte-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intention is to store the sound data in a `byte[]`, the best approach is not to get an `AudioInputStream` at all.  Instead, just use a plain `InputStream`.

The `AudioInputStream` typically strips the first bytes from an input stream (because they contain formatting data) and then only provides the frames or samples of that stream.  Doing it using an `InputStream` on the other hand, you should be able to get all the bytes.  Then once the entire data is in a byte array, an `AudioInputStream` can be formed from the byte array (if needed).

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

Use apache commons [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) to read the bytes from the wav file.

```
        InputStream is = -> your FileInputStream
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(is, os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();

        byte[] ba = os.toByteArray();
```

You cannot read it directly to a ByteArrayOutputStream or you´re gonna get

```
java.io.IOException: stream length not specified
at com.sun.media.sound.WaveFileWriter.write(Unknown Source)
at javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.write(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Call to IOUtils.copy() never returns. I have used the syntax you have specified. Commons version - 2.4.

Comment: strange. it seems your audioinputstream can't be consumed

Comment: I have used the code from [link](http://www.codejava.net/coding/capture-and-record-sound-into-wav-file-with-java-sound-api). I used the code in the above answer to read the AudioInputStream. 
PS: I moved the declaration of ais (AudioInputStream reference) from start() to make ais a field of class. So it is visible in finish().
Modified sampleRate to 44100.0, sampleSizeInBits to 16 and channels to 1.

Comment: you can capture to a file and then read the bytes from it. You cannot capture directly to a byte[] because the java audio API does not allow you to do that (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/198679/convert-audio-stream-to-wav-byte-array-in-java-without-temp-file)

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what exactly you want: byte array with data or byte array with WAV file inside. Byte array with only sound data is a very simple task: copy from AudioInputStream  to ByteArrayOutputStream.

The second case is more complex. In this case you should read from AudioInputStream to ByteArrayOutputStream and then form WAVE header. I can provide you two examples. I hope they will help you.

[How to record audio to byte array](http://privateblog.by/kak-zapisat-zvuk-na-java-v-byte-massiv) - it is example of recording audio to byte array with wave file inside.

[How to detect sound](http://privateblog.by/detektirovanie-zvuka-na-java/) - it shows how AudioInputStream can be processed.