# How to read mp3 file to a byte array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, audio

I want to read the content of the `.mp3` file into a byte array(Not including  header and metadata). For this purpose I'm using following code.

```
File myFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Kaushal28\\Desktop\\a.mp3");
    byte[] samples;

    AudioInputStream is = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(myFile);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);      //So we can use readFully()
    try{
        AudioFormat format = is.getFormat();
        samples = new byte[(int)(is.getFrameLength() * format.getFrameSize())];
        dis.readFully(samples);
    }
    finally{
        dis.close();
    }
```

Here is the link where it is posted: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169044/java-how-to-store-the-audio-data-in-a-byte-array).

I executed this code with a mp3 file of a song. but got following exception:

```
javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException: could not get audio input stream from input file
```

I've also tried this with .au file type, but got same exception.

For this I searched on Internet and found this: [This SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570841/cant-get-audio-file-to-play).

It says that all wav formats are not supported by java. Is it also true for .mp3 file formats?  Or any other reasons due to which I'm getting this exception?

Comment: You need to use a separate library for mp3, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/24337995/2670892

Comment: I don't want to play. I want to store it in array for further manipulations.

Comment: The Javazoom library that answer links to provides the code to do that.